# Javascript return variable from function and pass as parameter

Tags: javascript, react-native, parameters, return

I got this function to insert image into firebase. What I am trying to do is select image, insert the image to firebase storage, get its downloadURL, then insert new record for account along with the downloadURL.

```
uploadAsByteArray = async (pickerResultAsByteArray, progressCallback) => {

  try {
var metadata = {
  contentType: 'image/jpeg',
};

let name = new Date().getTime() + "-media.jpg"
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
var ref = storageRef.child('assets/' + name)
let uploadTask = ref.put(pickerResultAsByteArray, metadata)

uploadTask.on('state_changed', function (snapshot) {

  progressCallback && progressCallback(snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes)

  var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
  console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');

}, function (error) {
  console.log("in _uploadAsByteArray ", error)
}, function () {
  var downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
  //console.log("_uploadAsByteArray ", uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL)
  console.log('URLLLLL ' + downloadURL);


  // save a reference to the image for listing purposes
  var ref = firebase.database().ref('assets');
  ref.push({
    'URL': downloadURL,
    //'thumb': _imageData['thumb'],
    'name': name,
    //'coords': _imageData['coords'],
    'owner': firebase.auth().currentUser && firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
    'when': new Date().getTime()
  })
});
  return downloadURL;
  } catch (ee) {
console.log("when trying to load _uploadAsByteArray ", ee)
  }
}
```

I wanted to return variable downloadURL from this function and pass as parameter to my addNewAccount(), I am getting undefined.

```
addNewAccount = (downloadURL) => {
  console.log(downloadURL);
}
```

Comment: Or is there any way to set the downloadURL to global variable?

Comment: Where you call `addNewAccount` ?

Comment: When my submit button on click. Basically I click on the image button to get image, it add new image into firebase storage then return downloadURL, then I continue to fill in all other fields, and proceed to insert the record into firebase.

Comment: It should work like this: 
firebase return your `downloadURL` you are setting it's in `state` of component or app state, and with submit you pass this variable like `onSubmit={() => addNewAccount(state.downloadURL)}`

Comment: @Andrew Sorry but the only part I needed to change is the parameter for addNewAccount right? Other than that, the uploadAsByteArray no need to change anything right

Comment: Could you give a link to this page at github?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need use call back, like you do with `progressCallback` and pass there your `downloadURL`:

Then here you will have your `downloadURL` in progress:

```
api.uploadAsByteArray(byteArray, (downloadURL) => {
  //console.log('downloadURL' + downloadURL)
  this.setState({ downloadURL: downloadURL})
})
```

After `setState` you will have a downloadURL in the components state and can pass it in `addNewAccount`:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.addNewAccount(downloadURL)}>
```

Your function uploadAsByteArray:

```
uploadAsByteArray = async(pickerResultAsByteArray, progressCallback) => {

    try {
        var metadata = {
            contentType: 'image/jpeg',
        };

        let name = new Date().getTime() + "-media.jpg"
        var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
        var ref = storageRef.child('assets/' + name)
        let uploadTask = ref.put(pickerResultAsByteArray, metadata)

        uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot) {

            progressCallback && progressCallback(snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes)

            var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
            console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');

        }, function(error) {
            console.log("in _uploadAsByteArray ", error)
        }, function() {
            var downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
            //console.log("_uploadAsByteArray ", uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL)
            console.log('URLLLLL ' + downloadURL);


            // save a reference to the image for listing purposes
            var ref = firebase.database().ref('assets');
            ref.push({
                'URL': downloadURL,
                //'thumb': _imageData['thumb'],
                'name': name,
                //'coords': _imageData['coords'],
                'owner': firebase.auth().currentUser && firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
                'when': new Date().getTime()
            })
            progressCallback(downloadURL);
        });
    } catch (ee) {
        console.log("when trying to load _uploadAsByteArray ", ee)
    }
}
```

Comment: But now it is throwing me an error at the onPress there. The error message is cant find variable: downloadURL. Also, when i print out the downloadURL in callback, it printed out 0 or 1 only. It is not the exact url

Comment: Have you do instead `return downloadURL` a `progressCallback(downloadURL);  ?

Comment: Sorry but you mean add a return statement to return downloadURL in uploadAsByteArray()?

Comment: Yep, instaed of return just pass your veriable to callback

Comment: Sorry but how do I apply it in my case? I tried with the return downloadURL in the question but it does not work

Comment: Also, there is an error I mentioned above for this part this.addNewAccount(downloadURL)

Comment: Glad to help :)